# C++ comparing string operation speed

Tags: c++, string

lets say I have 3 std::string A, B and AB.

A is anything, B is anything and AB is A and B together.

which is these options is faster to do (and why):

```
int main(){
    string A = "abc", B = "def", AB = "abcdef";
    A += B;
    cout<<A<<endl;
}

output: abcdef
```

or

```
int main(){
    string A = "abc", B = "def", AB = "abcdef";
    A = AB;
    cout<<A<<endl;
}

output: abcdef
```

?

I'm asking this because I have a program that will execute this operation lots of times and I need to know which is faster, but I don't have testing inputs yet.

I'm using minGW for C++11

Comment: Have you tried timing it?

Comment: `A=AB` is not even valid C++. Your question seems confused.

Comment: `which is these options is faster to do (and why):`  -- Post a real program, not fake code.  And even then, time the code you posted with optimizations turned on.

Comment: I tried and it seems the same but I didn't do a research testing on it, I'm asking cause someone may already have done. Also, AB is just a NAME for a string that is A + B

Comment: can the downvoters explain something?

Comment: Sure. You didn't post valid code and you're asking us for something that you could quite easily do yourself with a profiler .

Comment: yes. I downvoted, and I agree with all the comments above: No real code, no sharing your own benchmark, no explanation of why you care and in what context, and why would you even compare an operation like A + B with a constant?

Comment: @Marcus, "I have three std::string A, B and AB" - hence A=AB is perfectly valid assignment.

Comment: yes, but then your question simply makes even less sense.

Comment: @Daniel We don't know what compiler you're using, what compiler options you used, how "AB" became A + B (whether it was hardcoded in, concatenated previously by some set of operations, etc.).

Comment: I'm not getting the point here. Let me edit my question.

Comment: *I'm not getting the point here* -- So posting, at the very least, what compiler and options you're using isn't a valid requirement?

Comment: I hope it's better now... I'm just asking which of the options is faster in general, I dont know why it is not making sense.

Comment: @Daniel If you're not going to run tests at least [see this](http://gcc.godbolt.org/).  Enter your code there and look at the code generation to determine which should be faster and why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so the question basically boils down to comparison between two assignments:

```
A+=B;
```

and

```
A=AB;
```

Well, theoretically I would expect the += version to be more efficient, because you have to copy over only half as many characters. That is assuming that A was initially allocated with enough room to hold a longer string without needing to be re-allocated.

Comment: ...or the move-assignment operator along with additional optimizations (even if small) you could realistically expect the performance between the two to be the same or nearly the same. The only real way to know is to profile it effectively.